# PuTTY continuous scrolling

Tags: putty, scrolling

I am trying to capture (via session logging) a very long config output from a device.  Is there a way I can stop PuTTY from pausing on each line?  My finger is getting very tired from holding the enter key down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PuTTY has *no such thing* as pausing on each line or screen; this is done entirely by your remote device. The exact instructions therefore depend on your device's firmware.

Usually, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> will skip a whole screen rather than single line.

Most devices also have an option to disable pagination:

- ArubaOS: `no paging`
- Cisco IOS: `terminal length 0`
- Cisco ASA: `terminal pager 0`
- HP Comware: `screen-length disable`
- HP ProCurve: `no page`
- Palo Alto: `set cli pager off`
- TP-Link: `terminal length 0` (or `no clipaging` in config mode)

Consider also retrieving the configuration via FTP, TFTP, SCP, SFTP, or similar.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just skip the (much slower) rendering and sending of each line to your session and write to a file locally that you then download?

Command > /path/to/file